# How to keep my Debian system with the latest packages?

Tags: debian, package-management

Most of the "Software" I install on my server needs to be the latest release (Java, Tomcat, MySQL-Cluster). So I never have the luck, that there are pre-built Debian packages (in the distribution) available. Therefore all the software is downloaded from the project-webpage and built from source.

Now my question is, what is the correct way to install them on my Debian system?

My main problem is, when installing them directly from the source, they are not included in the package management (with aptitude). Checkinstall seems to not really be suggested to be used and equiv also has drawbacks. Is the only correct way to handle this by building my own packages with dh_make and dpkg-buildpackage?

What are you doing if you always need the latest version?

Answer (score 10):

Wanting more recent packages is a common issue on any OS. Debian's release cycle has averaged 2 years in recent years, so towards the end of this cycle, it is perhaps a more pressing issue. One way of mitigating this is to move to testing towards the end of the stable release cycle, when the next version is almost stable. It is not clear from the question whether it is talking about stable on more generally about testing and/or unstable as well. Regardless, having the most recent version can be an issue even if one if running unstable, as the most recent version may not be packaged yet. Debian developers/packagers are volunteers, so they may get bored, or busy with other things, with the result that the package languishes.

For simplicity and concreteness I assume in what follows that the plan is to backport a package to stable, but it applies more generally. So, here is what I do if I want a more recent version of software that is not present in stable, in an approximate order.

1. Look for the package in [Debian Backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/). Sometimes you can find a package that is recent enough to satisfy your purposes. However, it is often the case that these packages are outdated compared to the version in unstable or experimental or upstream.
2. Try to install the package directly
   from testing, unstable, or
   experimental. If stable has not
   diverged much from whatever version
   you are trying to install from, this
   may work. You'll know this approach
   is a bad one if the system starts
   trying to  install or upgrade basic
   packages from the more recent
   version. Suppose you are trying to
   install from unstable, then

   ```
   apt-get install packagename/unstable
   ```

   is the first thing to try. With
   versions of apt in stable, this will
   often fail, as it requires other
   packages from unstable, and this
   incantation only ups the preference
   of `packagename` sufficiently high for
   it to be installed in unstable. If
   you don't understand what this
   means, go away and read `man
   apt_preferences`. Carry on adding
   dependencies from unstable, making
   sure that it is not trying to
   upgrade basic packages. For example,
   if it starts trying to upgrade libc6
   or X or KDE or Gnome, abort
   immediately. It is usually fine if
   it is tries to upgrade other
   packages from the same source
   package, as these are usually
   tightly coupled together. To see
   what source package a binary package
   depends on, do

   ```
   apt-cache showsrc packagename
   ```

   Since lots of stuff depends on the
   GNU C library (libc6) this used to
   be a problem. More recently, the API
   seems to have stabilized, so it is
   now more often possible to get away
   with not having to upgrade it. If a
   package satisfies its runtime
   dependencies on stable, but still
   does not work correctly, file a bug.
   If the packager tells you it is not
   a bug, they are wrong. :-)
3. Backport the package yourself from
   testing, unstable or experimental.

   As mentioned above, backports is one
   option, but often these packages are
   outdated compared to the version in
   unstable or experimental or
   upstream.

   This can often require a recursive
   dependency build loop type thing.
   You first    need to get the build
   dependencies with

   ```
   apt-get build-dep packagename
   ```

   If this fails because one of the
   dependencies is not recent enough,
   you'll need to backport that
   dependency first. This can spriral
   out of control. I usually give up if
   I have to deal with more than 2
   levels of recursion. Note however, that
   the real dependencies aren't necessarily
   as tight as stated ie. an older version may
   work. The packager often don't try to find
   the oldest version of a build (or, indeed, runtime)
   dependency that will work.
4. Check for the availability of packages from the corresponding
   upstream. Ideally these would match your distribution version, but
   you might also be able to rebuild them if necessary.
5. Create packages for version of the software more recent
   than the most recent packages in
   testing/unstable/experimental.
   This can be relatively challenging, but still sometimes
   surprisingly doable. The first thing
   to note is that if you are trying to
   package a more recent version of a
   package that is already in Debian,
   you are already starting with a big
   advantage, namely that you have the
   existing packaging to work with. Just
   do

   ```
   apt-get source packagename
   ```

   and `apt-get` will download the
   corresponding source package,
   including the debian subdirectory
   where the packaging lives. Note
   furthermore that these days, this
   packaging often lives inside some
   verson control repository (git seems
   popular with Debian) and stable apt
   (currently [0.8.10.3](http://packages.debian.org/source/stable/apt))
   helpfully tells
   you where this is when  you invoke
   `apt-get source`. You should look at
   this, because the packagers may have
   more recent versions of the
   packaging than corresponds to any
   released package. Eg.

   ```
   $ apt-get source mercurial
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
     NOTICE: 'mercurial' packaging is maintained in the 'Svn' version control system at:
     svn://svn.debian.org/python-apps/packages/mercurial/trunk
   ```

   Alternatively, you could simply use

   ```
   apt-cache showsrc mercurial | grep Vcs
   ```

   to list the repository.

   If the package is badly out of date, you may have to make modifications to the
   package, refresh the applied patches but it is still usually a good starting
   point. Debian seems to be in the process of standardizing package management on
   quilt per the [dpkg-source 3.0 (quilt) 
   format](http://wiki.debian.org/Projects/DebSrc3.0), so that helps with patch refreshing.

   I'll conclude with a real-life example of how I backported the [Debian 
   package](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/pgf.html) of
   [pgf](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/). The last packaged version of 
   pgf was 2.00 in 2008, and since then 2.10 had been released. See the discussion 
   in [Please update to newest stable version of pgf 
   (2.10)](http://bugs.debian.org/606128), and my followup bug with a patch, [pgf: 
   patches against 2.0 Debian packaging](http://bugs.debian.org/618440). As it 
   turns out, the Debian packaging of pgf was very simple, and I just had to change 
   one line in the 2.10 packaging to make it work. I ended up quelling all the 
   [lintian](http://packages.qa.debian.org/l/lintian.html) complaints as well, but 
   that was strictly optional.

Comment: The last sentence of the first paragraph can be misleading. Please make it clear that you the problem only occurs *sometimes*. The way you put makes it seems like DDs are generally like that.

Comment: @Tshepang: Good point. Is it Ok now?

Comment: Yeah, much better.

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly build your own packages, and that will work. However I would recommend using [backports](http://backports.debian.org/) first if what you want is available there.

Backports are Debian maintained and you get security updates for them.

Answer (score 3):

Building your own packages is the way to go (IMHO). Depending on the age of Debian's version of a package and what has changed, this can be as easy as replacing the filename of the source tarball in the package description and in the worst case you can still use it as a template for your own version.

Answer (score 2):

***What are you doing if you always need the latest version?***

1. As [already mentioned](https://serverfault.com/questions/230310/debian-always-latest-packages-best-practice/230353#230353), use backports.
2. Only a small subset of Debian packages are backported, so I suggest that you use [Debian Testing](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-ftparchives#s-testing). It offers a nice balance between stability and recency, and is in a sense, like a rolling distro.
3. If you are a bit more daring, use [Debian Unstable](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-ftparchives#s-unstable). It's claimed to be reasonably stable. Some even go as far as claiming it's more stable than some other distro's "stable" releases. Anyways, Unstable is where new package versions normally land. They normally sit there for about 10 days, to allow for testing, before migrating to Testing.
4. Even using these two, you might still find yourself not having the latest versions. In that case have a look at [Debian Experimental](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental). It's normally used when the new packages are too disruptive for the normal archives (Unstable and Testing).
5. If Experimental still doesn't have new enough software versions, go look at [Ubuntu's PPA's](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). I've seen software versions there more recent than what all the above archives lack. Use it with caution though, since Ubuntu isn't 100% compatible with Debian (but for most cases, there shouldn't be any issues).
6. If the above fail, I guess just build your own packages, [as mentioned](https://serverfault.com/questions/230310/debian-always-latest-packages-best-practice/230319#230319).

Comment: People saying Debian's unstable is more stable than other distro's stable are joking at best. Unstable changes every day, stable is a fixed repository. Unstable does not mean it'll crash, but it means the developers make a lot of changes to the packages.  Stable means it's released, and only security fixes will be added.  I never had weird crashes running unstable.  I did see packages break and dependency problems after upgrading tho, beware ;-)  How that all compares to other distro's "stable" releases is beyond me.  There's no "more stable" in this context. It changes or it doesn't.

Comment: @ArjanDrieman: actually those people are not joking, and in that context they are referring to it being more crash-proof.

Comment: They're still joking at best. I really have seen people joke about it. A micro distribution flame ;-) I've used a few distro's over time, and have never had weird crashes running any of the other either,  People who say that seriously can't back it up with research or stats. That might be ignorance, arrogance, prejudice, anything... but is that better than a joke? Can you tell me who these mysterious "Some" are?, so I can ask them for their research? "Some even go as far"... those are weasel words. What would you like in an answer, facts, or popular opinion and ambiguous claims?

Comment: @Arjan Drieman: I actually agree unstable, can 'somtimes' live up to its name.  You trade stability for going closer to the edge, anyone who claims it's not the case is disingenuous at best.  Overall it is surprisingly stable, but stability is not the highest priority for unstable.  I also tend to agree with you, in regards to 'slippery' wordage. It's almost a defense mechanism over here, as any absolute/direct statement is immediately attacked.